How to not allow PiP window overlay in some areas (like navbar) in iOS apps?
In iOS, Home Screen and some system apps (like App Store) have the design that makes PiP windows not overlay the bottom NavBar. How to do that in my app?
I am making a SwiftUI chat app with an input box on the bottom of the screen. How can I do to avoid PiP video display on that input box and make it slightly move upwards like in App Store?
Like this:
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                ComposerInputView(
                    factory: DefaultViewFactory.shared,
                    text: $viewModel.text,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

